# Как правильно: не могут или не может отсутствовать более двух человек?

Tags: орфография

Как правильно: "Одновременно не могут отсутствовать более двух человек" или "не может отсутствовать более двух человек"?

Answer (score 3):

**Оба варианта возможны.**

В случае препозиции сказуемого можно выбрать ед. число: Одновременно **не может** отсутствовать более двух человек.

Розенталь §184. Сказуемое при подлежащем – количественно-именном сочетании (счетном обороте) [XLIII. СОГЛАСОВАНИЕ СКАЗУЕМОГО С ПОДЛЕЖАЩИМ](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/64.htm)

При обозначении **приблизительного количества** (путем постановки числительного впереди существительного или путем вставки слов **около, свыше, больше, меньше** и т.п.) сказуемое может стоять **как в форме единственного, так и в форме множественного числа** (второй способ согласования все чаще встречается в наше время), например:
а)     Под навесиком **помещалось** не больше четырех ребят... (Макаренко); 
б)       Не менее двадцати дам... **сидели** на зеленых скамейках и неотрывно глядели в сторону бухты (Сергеев-Ценский);

Answer (score 2):

Да тут всё просто. "Не может отсутствовать более двух человек" означает, что такая ситуация не может иметь место. То есть глагол "может" относиться к событию/ситуации. А в случае "Не могут отсутствовать более двух человек" - глагол "могут" относится к отсутствующим людям. Оба варианта правильные.

Answer (score 1):

Если по части грамматики, то оба варианта правильны, как уже сказали. 
Но с более общих позиций правильно будет что-то наподобие ***"Не должно быть более двух отсутствующих"***, остальное - или тяжеловесно стилистически, или вообще плохо.

"Отсутствовать", "одновременно", да еще в сочетание "с более чем" - это какое-то нагромождение канцеляризмов. А как можно отсутствовать не одновременно? По очереди? Тогда это какое-то неправильное отсутствие... Сразу вспоминается "при наличии отсутствия"